# Seal around hvac ac lines

Tags: hvac, safety, pest, seal

I want to seal outdoor AC lines. I have a gap. Is it safe to use gap filling foams? Is it flameble with the copper tube
[image]

Comment: Or this? [What is the correct way to seal/flash coolant lines through siding?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81395/what-is-the-correct-way-to-seal-flash-coolant-lines-through-siding)

Comment: Or this? [What should I use to seal the hole where my central air enters the house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91744/what-should-i-use-to-seal-the-hole-where-my-central-air-enters-the-house)

Comment: Or this? [Is sprayfoam suitable for a waterproof seal around AC lines through external wall penetrations?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/282772/35141)

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and be sure to search before you ask.